# What does this code from AuthKit do? (where are these functions and methods defined?)

Tags: python, authkit

I am trying to [implement my own authentication method for AuthKit](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/authkitcookbook/Implement+Your+Own+Authentication+Method) and am trying to figure out how some of the built-in methods work. In particular, I'm trying to figure out how to update the `REMOTE_USER` for `environ` correctly.

This is how it is handled inside of `authkit.authenticate.basic` but it is pretty confusing. I cannot find anyplace where `REMOTE_USER` and `AUTH_TYPE` are defined. Is there something strange going on here and if so, what is it?

```
def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    environ['authkit.users'] = self.users
    result = self.authenticate(environ)
    if isinstance(result, str):
        AUTH_TYPE.update(environ, 'basic')
        REMOTE_USER.update(environ, result)
    return self.application(environ, start_response)
```

There are actually a number of all uppercase things like this that I cannot find a definition for. For example, where does `AUTHORIZATION` come from below:

```
def authenticate(self, environ):
    authorization = AUTHORIZATION(environ)
    if not authorization:
        return self.build_authentication()
    (authmeth, auth) = authorization.split(' ',1)
    if 'basic' != authmeth.lower():
        return self.build_authentication()
    auth = auth.strip().decode('base64')
    username, password = auth.split(':',1)
    if self.authfunc(environ, username, password):
        return username
    return self.build_authentication()
```

I feel like maybe I am missing some special syntax handling for the `environ` dict, but it is possible that there is something else really weird going on here that isn't immediately obvious to someone as new to Python as myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at that source I see it has an (evil)

```
from paste.httpheaders import *
```

that is one way otherwise-mysterious barenames could suddenly appear in the code (which is exactly why this idiom is a very, very bad practice).  I can't be sure that's how those identifiers suddenly and inexplicably materialize, but it's a possibility.

Comment: Looks like that is where it came from. I wish I knew why doing `AUTH_TYPE.update(environ, 'basic')` seemed at the time to be superior to `environ['AUTH_TYPE'] = 'basic'` (which is actually less characters)